# Check if a paragraph starts with a character and apply an HTML style on it if so

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

I'm using a textarea to write a text like this:

```
%this is my text

%%also text

simple text

%%%last text
```

If a paragraph starts with `%`, it should show the whole line with `<h1>`, if there are 2, `%%`, it should be `<h2>` and so on until `<h3>`.

For the above example it must return:

```
<h1>this is my text</h1>

<h2>also text</h2>

simple text

<h3>last text</h3>
```

I've done this:

```
  var result = inputVal.replace('%', '<h1>');
```

it replaces the symbol at the beginning but I don't know how to add the closing tag at the end of the line. And also how to count how many `%` are so it can show ,  or other ones.

Is the a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please reply if my answer did help you ? @leo-messi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function convertToTags(textToConvert) {
    // the current text.
    const str = textToConvert
    // get me the number of the tags.
    const tagsCount = str.split("").filter(x => x === "%").length

    // if no hash signs return the result
    if (tagsCount === 0) return textToConvert;

    // give me the text without the tags
    const text = str.replaceAll("%", "")
    // tie all the pieces together.
    const result = `<h${tagsCount}>${text}</h${tagsCount}>`
    return result;
}

console.log(convertToTags("%this is my text"))
console.log(convertToTags("%%also text"))
console.log(convertToTags("simple text"))
console.log(convertToTags("%%%last text"))
```

This will work for h1 to hn.

```
// the current text. 
const str = '%%%last text'
// get me the number of the tags.
const tagsCount = str.split("").filter(x => x === "%").length

// give me the text without the tags
const text = str.replaceAll("%", "")
// tie all the pieces together.
const result = `<h${tagsCount}>${text}</h${tagsCount}>`
```

You can wrap that code in a function

```
function convertToTags(textToConvert) {
    // the current text.
    const str = textToConvert
    // get me the number of the tags.
    const tagsCount = str.split("").filter(x => x === "%").length

    // if no hash signs return the result
    if (tagsCount === 0) return textToConvert;

    // give me the text without the tags
    const text = str.replaceAll("%", "")
    // tie all the pieces together.
    const result = `<h${tagsCount}>${text}</h${tagsCount}>`
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can loop through all the lines and regenerate the string in each iteration.

**Demo:**

```js
var inputVal = `%this is my text

%%also text

simple text

%%%last text`;

inputVal = inputVal.split('\n').map(function(v){
  if(v.trim() && v.startsWith('%')){
    var c = v.split(' ')[0].match((/%/g) || []).length;
    v = `<h${c}>${v.substring(c)}</h${c}>`;
  }
  return v;
}).join('\n');

console.log(inputVal);
```